# How to extract the value after arrow for all digits in google sheet?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, extract

[image]

Hi everyone,

I want to extract the values after the arrow. If there is only one value in the cell, then just take the value.

I'm using `REGEXEXTRACT` to achieve this. It works well when the raw data are 2 digits or 3 digits in column M and column P as shown in the screenshot above. However, the syntax in `REGEXEXTRACT` is not correct when it comes to 4 digits (column T). May I know how should I modify the the syntax in `REGEXEXTRACT` so that the formula can cater for 2, 3 or 4 digits? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

### Edit

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A&"", ":?\d+,?\d+.\d+$")*1))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi player0, I tried your method, it is still the same, I attached the screenshot under the edit section in my question.

Comment: `=QUERY(IMPORTHTML("https://www.marketbeat.com/stocks/NASDAQ/AMZN/price-target/", "table", 2), "Select Col6 where Col6 is not null ",1)`, this is where I get the value, in case you need it.